# Vite not serving files from public folder in production

Tags: reactjs, vercel, vite

I recently shifted my react website from CRA to Vite to enjoy to faster builds. Everything is working well except vite is not serving files from public directory in production instead it redirects to 404 page of react app. It work fine in dev.

I am using:
Vite: 2.9.13
React: 18.2.0

##### Expected Behaviour:

https://movielust.in/images/logo.png Should return a png image.

##### Actual behaviour:

https://movielust.in/images/logo.png Return a 404 page from react app.

##### Directory structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── components
│   └── pages
│   
├── public
│   ├── images
|   |   └── logo.png
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── sitemap.html
│   └── manifest.json
|   
├── vite.config.js
├── .tsconfig
├── package.json
└── index.html
```

##### Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
/* eslint import/no-extraneous-dependencies:off */
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';
import StylelintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-stylelint';

const eslintPlugin = eslint({ cache: true, cacheLocation: './.eslintcache' });
const svgr = svgrPlugin({
    svgrOptions: {
        icon: true,
        svgo: true,
    },
});

const stylelintPlugin = StylelintPlugin({
    fix: false,
    quite: false,
    include: [/.*\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/],
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    cache: true,
    cacheLocation: './.stylelintcache',
});

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: 'build',
    },
    plugins: [
        react({ babel: { plugins: ['babel-plugin-styled-components'] } }),
        VitePWA({ registerType: 'autoUpdate', devOptions: { enabled: true } }),
        svgr,
        eslintPlugin,
        stylelintPlugin,
    ],
});
```

I don't if this is a bug or problem that I created so please let me know any solution anyone knows.

Comment: Did you make sure of file permissions on the server ?

Comment: @MohammadTbeishat  Yes

Comment: I use Vercel to host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got resolved after upgrading to Vite 3.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened your link and I can see your image. Make sure of removing your cache. Or open the page in a private session!

[image]

Comment: Yes it got auto resolved after upgrading to Vite 3